# Perform a POST request in the background using React Native (expo)

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo

I am relatively new to React Native but I have a functional codebase. My app sends orders from the waiter to the kitchen. I have tested it in stores. What I need is to somehow post the order to my web app without waiting for the server to respond (assuming that all is ok) and navigate directly to the list of tables some sort of async/background job. Do I implement this using some background tasks? if yes could you point in the right direction? Also if possible no redux answers I don't know how to use it yet.

Sorry for the messy code I'm getting better.

```
  onSendOrder = () => {
    //console.log('Sending Order');
    //console.log("table_id", this.props.navigation.getParam("table_id"));


    // trim the contents.
    let order_items = this.state.order;
    // //console.log(order_items);

  //   const myArray = this.state.data.filter(function( obj ) {
  //     return obj.checked !== false;
  // });

    var i;
    // let total_cost = 0;
    let contents = []
    // //console.log('total_cost: ', total_cost);
    // let items = order.items;
    for (i = 0; i < order_items.length; i++) {

        contents = order_items[i].contents.filter(function( obj ) {
          return obj.checked !== false;
      });


        // //console.log(contents);

        order_items[i].contents = contents;

      // total_cost += this.compute_item_cost(order[i]);
    }


    this.setState({loading:true});

    //console.log('Trimed order items: ',order_items);


    let order = {
      "items": {
        "credentials": this.state.credentials, 
        "personnel_id": 1,
        "store_id": 1,
        "order_comment": "",
        "order_id": "",
        "timestamp": "None",
        "table_id": this.props.navigation.getParam("table_id"),
        "order_items": order_items
      }
    };

    var host = this.props.navigation.getParam('url', 'something.com');
    // //console.log('SENDING ORDER TO HOST: ', host)
    //console.log('ORDER OBJECT', order);
    fetch("http://" + host + "/api/v1/mobile/order?store_id=1", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(order)
    })

      .then(response => {
        // //console.log(response.status)
        // this.props.navigation.navigate('Table', { order: this.state.order });

        const statusCode = response.status;
        const data = response.json();
        return Promise.all([statusCode, data]);
      })
      .then((server_response) => {
        //console.log("RESULTS HERE:", server_response[0])

        this.setState({
          order: [],
        }, function () {
          if (server_response[0] == 201) {
            //console.log('Success Going to Table')
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Table', { order: this.state.order });

          } else {
            //console.log('Failed going to table')
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Table', { order: this.state.order });

          }

        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        //console.error(error);
      })
  };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
```

Comment: Please provide more details for your answer.